# (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL error: certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, sqlalchemy, psycopg2

I am trying to use Sqlalchemy package to be able to connect to Redshift datawarehouse.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import psycopg2


red_engine=create_engine('redshift+psycopg2://admin:XXXXXXXXX@IP:PORT/DBNAME')

test = pd.read_sql_query(query,red_engine)
```

Error message I get is :

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) SSL error: certificate verify failed
```

I am unable to see why this SSL veirifcation is falling all, used to go smoothly earlier.

Comment: where you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, my DB is hosted on AWS and it turned out i was using the Static IP to connect to it, whereas I should have been using the Dynamic IP for the same.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same error. I updated the sqlalchemy-redshift package to the latest, 0.7.0, which updates the certificates used to connect to Redshift.

To update, use `pip install -U sqlalchemy-redshift`.